# Custom Android permissions not showing in Settings

Tags: android, android-permissions

I created a brand new app in Android studio, and all I changed was the AndroidManifest.xml. I added the following, along with the references string values. I was expecting to see my custom permission listed in the App info page in settings, but it's not showing. For example, I can see that chrome browser uses a custom permission com.android.chrome.PRERENDER_URL. I would like to show this permission.

The real reason to do this is that I have a preload version of my app and a market version. I want to use a signature protection level such that if the preload version was installed I could use these extra things that I build into it. So basically I would like to see visually in the settings page that the preload version has this extra permission but the Play Store one doesn't. Furthermore I would like to see that the Play Store version inherits the permission from the preload version if it installs over it. Added complexity is also that eventually I will programmatically disable this permission if I choose to, but that's later.

For now I just want some information about what's visible to the user. I think the API say that signature level permissions are "transparent" so maybe that doesn't show. But on my test app, I'm using normal permission, which it should show right?

```
<permission android:name="com.mytestapp.permission.YO"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:description="@string/custom_permission_desc"
            android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.mytestapp.permission.YO" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal permissions are granted automatically, only Dangerous permissions show in your app settings try changing it to that. Source [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous)